# How do I compensate for a changed directory?

Tags: c#

I am developing a simple C# console application for use in an industrial setting. This application takes a product id number, and then configures an XML file and saves it to a folder location. The operators then load this XML file into a laser printer that engraves data onto a product. This app will be used on multiple computers, and not installed by me.

Right now I have hardcoded in filepaths for the XML file templates (C:\XmlGen\SourceTempplates), and the location that the configured files are saved (C:\XMLGen\OutputXml). Now, if the app gets installed on a computer and moved somewhere, the application will not be able to find the templates or save the configured files. Is there a way that I can write these filepaths so that the application can still find the files? (Say for example, it gets installed to a D:\ drive instead of C).

Thanks! Let me know if I need to provide more info.

Comment: Use: `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. Unless you cange that it will point to your exe file's directory. Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?view=net-5.0 - then use `Path.Combine`.

Comment: I think you need to store these directories as configuration, and set them during installation. The simplest option is probably [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=net-5.0) if you're using .NET Framework, or the [appsettings.json if using .NET Core or .NET 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Its generally a good practice to use defined environment folder to store application generated files instead of using hardcoded drive letter.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```